# How to Take action for user using Accessibility android..?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

Android Documentation says an app can take action on behalf of user like selecting a UI element using Accessibility services from API level 14. Can any one tell me  how to do that or help me with some sample Code of it..?

Comment: I already did some explanations here [How to use Accessibility Services for “Taking Action for Users”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125940/how-to-use-accessibility-services-for-taking-action-for-users)

Answer (score 0):

Google's TalkBack is open source.  Seems like an excellent place to start.

https://github.com/google/talkback